# What could prevent a motorised CD player drawer from opening after not being used for an extended period of time?

Tags: electrical

Many years ago, I used to use a CD player that had an opening drawer - you'd press a button, the drawer would open, you'd insert the CD and then either push the drawer closed or use the same button. For some unknown reason to me now, this drawer somehow became damaged and after being off for several hours, it'd take around 50 presses of the button before the drawer would open. The button would press without issue, but each time I pressed the button I could hear the drawer sticking until it'd just open - if I kept using the button to open the drawer it'd open without issue, but if I stopped for an extended period of time I'd have to repeat the same process outlined above. This drawer would open outwards - it wasn't a flip-up kind of thing.

What could have changed in the period of time that I stopped opening the drawer to make it stick and not open? I'm not an expert on these types of things, and even though I no longer use this particular player I've always been interested to know!

Thanks.

Comment: Not a direct answer, and I think this is probably off topic for the site, but here is a [good video from Technology Connections](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6iyUSnrGk0) that explains how the changers work.

Comment: Be aware the DIY in our name is in the context of home repair, not general fix-it, so expect an off-topic close.  For that you can try lifehacks.se, but ifixit.com is better still.

Comment: the tray is probably ejected by a small motor that uses a pulley and a rubber o-ring to power the mechanism .... the rubber o-ring probably degraded and snapped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grease on the pinion gear could have dried out or the bearing surfaces, usually plastic on plastic. There are things that could cause this that we may not think about, but if you have ever opened one of these up the motors are tiny and many are monitored or they open and close based on how much current is being drawn, two much current you hear them try to cycle but they cannot. A paper clip or large needle will usually release a stuck tray (small hole usually just under the tray that opens) manually opening the drawer can sometimes get them working again for a while.

Comment: Yeah, that's surely what it is. It works after some time because the heat of the PC's operation is warming it up.  And yes, the motor control electronics are monitoring torque (~~ current) to save motor, mechanism and drive electronics.

Comment: if heat helps,it might be grease softening up. often dusty grease causes this. opening and closing the tray a few dozen times might thin out the grease to the point it will cold open again.